# Como separar los elementos en un array eliminando espacios, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

se me presenta un problema al separar elementos de una cadena, explico el problema, tenemos la cadena:
Si      4.073040    4.073040    1.357720
Quiero introducirla en un arreglo y que cada espacio del arreglo contenga un elemento, es decir

1. array[0] = Si array[1] = 4.073040 array[2] = 4.073040

Y asi, sin embargo al hacer uso de la funcion .split('  ') solo me separa los elementos conforme a la cantidad exacta de espacios que coloco en los argumentos de split, lo cual causa que en caso de que a veces varie la cantidad de espacios me concatene los valores en un solo espacio del arreglo quedando dos valores en un solo espacio del arreglo, por ejemplo

array[1] = 4.073040     4.073040

Como podria solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Con split pasándole un espacio como único parámetro haces que divida un string en cada espacio que encuentre. No deberías tener problema con eso.

```
var arreglo = variable.split(‘ ‘);
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que buscas, pero `.split()` acepta una expresión regular como argumento, en este caso la expresión `/ +/` representaría 1 o ilimitados espacios, entonces:

```js
const str = "4.073040 4.073040 1.357720   3.14     0.01";

const arr = str.split(/ +/g);

console.log(arr);
```